# Game Maker Studio - Check Collision With Subimages

Tags: collision-detection, mouse, game-maker

I have an `obj_roulette`, which contains 4 subimages, with `value 2-5` and `image_number 0-3`. The value result from roulette stored as var `global.roulette`.

Then, I make many `obj_meteorite`, which contains 4 subimages too, spawn from above with `random x value` and `random image_number`. Player can shoot them with left-mouse click.

This is what I want:

`If image_number obj_roulette is 0, and player shoot obj_meteorite with image_number 0, score +10.
If image_number obj_roulette is 0, and player shoot obj_meteorite with image_number 1, score -10.`

I don't know how to check collision between `mouse_x/mouse_y` and object `image_number`, and how to match `obj_roulette` `image_number` and `obj_meteorite` `image_number`.

Is it using collision checking? If it yes, then maybe the example in this link can help:
[link 1](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/position_meeting.html)

Please explain your answer. Thanks.

**update**

[Simple Diagram Image]

**update2**

[Simple Diagram Image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhh6j5ybvjc0i9a/Untitled-1.png?dl=0)

Comment: Not sure exactly what your asking but if you want to check if a meteorite is clicked in the step event you can also add (&& subimage == 1). Or if you mean that you want to check if the mouse is hovering over the meteorite then you would need to have conditions checking if mouse_x > self.x && mouse_x < self.x + sprite_width and repeat for the y axis.

Comment: @Daedric Where can I add `(&& subimage == 1)`? Just put it in the code? What I want is, after the player clicks a meteorite, the program will check which sub-image that was clicked. Is it match with the roulette or not.

Comment: Then you need multiple if statements that do different things based on the value of the subimage

Comment: @Daedric Can you give your code? Or if possible, can you give drag actions answer? Thanks

Comment: Can you add some diagrams because its really hard to solidify code when I don't know what your asking exactly.

Comment: @Daedric I added a diagram image

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is collision checking. Though, there's a little misunderstanding about variables that I'll first try to clarify before proceeding to a solution to your problem.

#### What does what

First of all, `image_number` is a constant ([YoYo Docs](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20properties/image_number.html) call it *read-only variable*) that gives you the number of sub-images of an object's current sprite (its `sprite_index`). If you want information about the actual frame to be drawn in the current step, you need to check the instance variable `image_index`.

That's the story: `sprite_index` is the sprite assigned to an object to be drawn; `image_index` is the current sub-image (or frame) of its animation to be drawn in the next *Draw()* call; finally, `image_number` is the total number of sub-image of `sprite_index`. When you change an object's `sprite_index` its `image_number` value will be automatically updated by the GM engine.

So, let's work with `image_number`. This variable is usually set to -1, which means its value will be updated (so that the animation cycles through) depending on `image_speed` value. I'm assuming your `image_speed`s are already set to 0, so that you can set the value of `image_index`es without having them changing automatically over time.

#### The first script

Now, to check mouse clicks onto objects depending on current `image_index`es, just add to the *Step Event* of `obj_meteorite` the following code:

```
// Check for an object being hit by the
// player: just a click, not continuously
if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left))
{
    // Is the mouse above me while clicking?
    if (position_meeting(mouse_x,mouse_y,self))
    {
        // Was that the right object to hit?
        if (image_index==global.roulette)
            score += 10;    // Yeah
        else
            score -= 10;    // Nope
        // You may want to destroy the object
        instance_destroy();
    }
}
```

The function [`collision_point()`](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/collision_point.html) belongs to the [Advanced Collision Checking](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/index.html) section in the YoYo Docs, as it's a more advanced way to check for instances whose collision masks include a particular point in the plane.

#### Optimization

This script is executed by every `obj_meteorite` every time the left mouse button is pressed. That means, if there are currently 7 instances of `obj_meteorite` then this script will be called and executed seven times. But we have one mouse cursor only, so we would just check what lies below it. We can achieve this by migrating such script into a new object called `obj_controller`, which will execute a slightly different script in its *Step Event*:

```
// Check for an object being hit by the
// player: just a click, not continuously
var my_inst;    // Local support variable
if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left))
{
    // Is there an instance below the mouse? Get its ID if yes
    my_inst = instance_position(mouse_x,mouse_y,obj_meteorite);
    // Is the mouse above the instance while clicking?
    if (my_inst!=noone)
    {
        // Was that the right object to hit?
        if (my_inst.image_index==global.roulette)
            score += 10;    // Yeah
        else
            score -= 10;    // Nope
        // You may want to destroy the object
        with (my_inst) instance_destroy();
    }
}
```

This way, the script is executed once only per mouse click. I guess your game isn't that complex and design optimization is no serious concern, but I suggest from time to time to check if your code can be designed and written differently to lower function calls and enhance your program performance, as it is good programming habit and practice.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I try your optimized code, but the score never changes, no matter which meteorite I click. Note: I already put the obj_controller in the room. Then, I try your first code. The result is, the meteorite won't spawn. Is it because obj_tempMeteorite that I created to create instance of obj_meteorite?

Comment: Well, I don't know what obj_tempMeteorite is or does, you are mentioning it for the first time

Comment: Well yeah, sorry, I thought it doesn't affect the problem. I updated my Simple Diagram Image, it contains obj_tempMeteorite

Comment: I can't see the point with your `obj_tempMeteorite`. Is it a controller? Does it deal with some sort of logic? It would be cleaner and clearer if the main logic was assigned to a single object (maybe the controller you mentioned) whilst coding other objects as far as their behaviors are concerned. An `obj_Meteorite` should be only responsible for its own movement, appearance, and _maybe_ interaction between user and itself.

Comment: I used `obj_tempMeteorite` to spawn `obj_meteorite`. I knew that from [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxl8Vdot2Po), and it's modified in my program. It works fine, so I think I don't need to change the events in `obj_tempMeteorite`

Comment: Well, if it works fine there's nothing to complain of :)) If meteorites don't spawn, you should check if `obj_tempMeteorite` is actually doing its job. If the score doesn't change, probably the scoring condition isn't triggered at all. Try again using the optimized code, but make sure `obj_tempMeteorite` is spawned. I have reason to believe this should work fine for you. Also, take a look to Shaun Spalding's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oua4Wbiu24Q) on Youtube, I found them educating and useful when I started learning how to use Game Maker Studio

Comment: I put draw score & set score to 0 in obj_controller? Is that the problem? Or, is the problem in obj_tempMeteorite?

Comment: Set score to 0 should be appear in controller create event, so that it is executed once only